# react-native-smart-splashscreen:verifyReleaseResources

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

in Generating the release APK
I get this error :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-smart-splashscreen:verifyReleaseResources'.

I using react-native-splashscreen
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.4

this below is my code

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.inclo"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}

splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you share package.json file

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-smart-splash-screen": "^2.3.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },

Comment: can you link your modules

Comment: by using react-native link?

Comment: yes react-native-link

Comment: yeah, i did that but still no working

Comment: android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: where can i put that code sir?

Comment: in gradle.properties

Comment: still not working sir :(. "This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used."

Comment: can u share android folder code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191644/discussion-between-lovepreet-singh-and-aditia-dananjaya).

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines of code in your ***android/build.gradle*** file

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to

```
node_modules/react-native-splashscreen/android/build.gradle
```

Edit and keep the `compileSdkVersion` `buildToolsVersion` `minSdkVersion` 
`targetSdkVersion` same as you have in

```
android/app/build.gradle
```

Sync the project again.

Run`./gradlew assembleRelease` from the terminal or try to regnerate  release APK.

Hope it works!